# Animate trajectory using Octave

Tags: animation, plot, octave

I have a set of `(x,y)` coordinates that describe the trajectory of an object. I'd like to animate this trajectory using GNU Octave.

The data set is quite large so I won't be able to redraw the entire plot at every iteration if I want the animation to be smooth. What functions are there that would allow me to "update" a plot rather than redraw it?

Also, I have another set of `(vx,vy)` points, which describe the speed of the object. I'd like my animated trajectory to take speed into account. What function should I use to have the program sleep for a couple of milliseconds as to make the trajectory animate at the same speed as the object?

(I already know Octave has functions such as `comet`, but I need to write my own animator.)

---

**Edit:** Here's what I have up until now. I expected this to run too fast and require me to use `pause`, but it's still pretty slow (`x` and `y` have 10001 elements).

```
bounds = [min(x) max(x) min(y) max(y)];
axis(bounds);

hold on
for k = 2 : length(x)
    plot(x(k-1:k), y(k-1:k));
    drawnow("expose");
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `set` command to change just the `XData` and `YData` data for a certain plot object `h`:

```
h = plot(my_xdata(0),my_ydata(0))
for i_=1:length(my_xdata)
    set(h, 'YData', my_ydata(i_))
    set(h, 'XData', my_xdata(i_))
    pause(sqrt(vx(i_)^2+vy(i_)^2))
end
```

The `pause(x)` command pauses for `x` seconds, which can be less than 1.

Comment: Thanks, `pause` is useful, but `set` is not what I want. I want the trace of the trajectory to remain. I'd like to know if there's some function that can update the trace of the plot, rather than redrawing a single point.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear what it is you want to animate.  Do you want to plot a line (the trajectory) and animate an object moving along that line?  Do you want to update the line itself?

Comment: Then you can use the same `set(h, 'YData', new_ydata)` command; it can update a point or a whole line.  I wrote my example updating a point because I thought that's what you wanted--one point moving around.

Comment: Isn't that the same as calling plot repeatedly?

Comment: Not quite.  The `plot` command creates a whole new plot, redrawing axes, etc.  When you use the `set` command it only changes one part of the plot you already made.  So, when you call `set(h, 'YData', ydata)` it just changes the y data in the plot object `h`, and redraws just the line which is the only part you want to change.

Comment: Great answer! (+1)  Your trick makes `comet` and `comet3` much faster.  I've elaborated (with attribution!) in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17773313/181638)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the "hold" command.  holding the plot keeps all previous data on the plot and the new data is added on top.

Comment: `hold` doesn't allow removal of previous data on the plot. When you animate a graph, you often want to add some data, as well as remove some other data. `hold` is generally used to plot multiple data series on a single graph.