# animate plot / trajectory in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, math, animation, 3d, octave

I'm trying to animate this spiral using matlab / octave I want it to spiral up or down

```
t = 0:0.1:10*pi;
r = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));
z = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));
plot3 (r.*sin(t), r.*cos(t), z);
```

[image: spiral]

I tried using a for loop to animate it but that just gives me a cone shape see code and image below

```
clear all, clc,clf,tic
t = 0:0.1:10*pi;
r = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));
z = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));

for ii=1:length(r)
    ii
    plot3 (r.*sin(t(ii)), r.*cos(t(ii)), z);
    hold on
    %pause (.00001)
end
```

Image [image]

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426378/how-to-animate-this-3d-plot-in-matlab/16426623#16426623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following appears to work in Octave 3.6.2

```
t = 0:0.1:10*pi;
r = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));
z = linspace (0, 1, numel (t));

figure
axis([-1 1 -1 1 0 1])
hold on

for ii=1:length(r)
    plot3 (r(ii)*sin(t(ii)), r(ii)*cos(t(ii)), z(ii),'*');
    pause (.001)
end
```

Comment: This is nice, though it does not provide a trajectory, only a sequence of points.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17773313/181638 for a solution that animates a trajectory.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `comet3()` package, which animates the trajectory through the plot:

```
delay = 0.001  % seconds
figure
comet3(r.*sin(t), r.*cos(t), z, delay);
```

This animates a continuous trajectory which I prefer over a discrete sequence of *'s.

The one downside is that the version of `comet` and `comet3` that shipped with Octave 3.6.4 are slow, regardless of the delay you use.  But this can be overcome by using the following trick courtesy of [andyras in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665740/181638):

```
% plot the first point to get started
h = plot3(x(1),y(1),z(1),"b");
axis([min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y), min(z), max(z)]);

% refresh the plot in a loop through the rest of the data
for k = 1:length(z);
   set(h, 'XData', x(1:k));
   set(h, 'YData', y(1:k));
   set(h, 'ZData', z(1:k));
   pause (0.001); % delay in seconds
       % alternatively could provide a velocity function
       % pause(sqrt(vx(k)^2+vy(k)^2+vz(k)^2));  
endfor
```

**Minor note**: once you've modified the function, you'll need to force Octave to reload it [as it won't do this by default](http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html3/octave_74.html).  You can either restart, or better yet use `clear comet` and `clear comet3`.  Then the next time those functions are called, their definitions will be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the prettiest, but these are the first changes you need to make to your code for it to do something close to what you want.

```
t = 0:0.1:10*pi;
z = linspace (1, 0, numel (t));
for ii=1:length(t)
    plot3 (z(ii)*sin(t(ii)),z(ii)*cos(t(ii)), z(ii));
    hold on
    pause (.00001)
end
```

Comment: Davin This just gives me an error "line 0: *All* edges undefined or out of range, thus no plot."

Comment: @RickT, never used octave before, I'm executing it on Matlab, presumably it's a compatibility/version issue then. You can try adding the `clear ...` line, or replacing `plot3` with `scatter3`, maybe that will help. If not, I'm fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the trajectory solution, but here is a spinning tornado.

```
phi = linspace(0, 10*pi, 300);
r = linspace (0, 1, 300);
z = linspace (0, 1, 300);
s = 100; %speed of turning
for t = 0:0.01:10 %t is time
  plot3 (r.*sin(phi+t*s), r.*cos(phi+t*s), z);
  pause(0.01)
end
```